# Eclipse/OSGi class loading issue - java.lang.LinkageError when trying to load a plugin with two versions

Tags: eclipse, osgi, classloader

In my Eclipse runtime, I have the following three plug-ins (file names simplified for better readability):

- javax.wsdl.1.4.0.jar
- javax.wsdl.1.5.1.jar
- eclipse.wsdl.jar, which has a version restriction on the dependency: [1.4.0, 1.5.0)

The dependencies of my own plugin look like this:
eclipse.wsdl
javax.wsdl : "1.4.0"

When my own plugin tries to use the class WSDLFactory, an error would be thrown:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation: loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@a7b0a7b" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/wsdl/factory/WSDLFactory" defined by loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@7c647c64"
```

Apparently, my own plug-in loads the 1.5.1 version of WSDLFactory, while eclipse.wsdl loads the 1.4.0 version of WSDLFactory, and this cause the conflict.  If I change the version restriction of my plugin to be [1.4.0, 1.5.1), the code would work just fine.  However, this is unacceptable since my code needs to support Eclipse 3.5 which forces to use javax.wsdl.1.5.1 intead of 1.4.0.

Are there any way to force my code to use the WSDLFactory loaded by eclipse.wsdl instead of trying to load its own?

And if possible at all, is there a way to force loading the lowest version (instead of highest) bundle?

**Update**: I tried both Require-Bundle and Import-Package and got different results in dev and release environment. Require-Bundle doesn't work for either one. Import-Package works in the dev environment but not in the release environment.

My question is, while Require-Bundle would try to load classes that are in the highest version of the plugin, does Import-Package NOT behave like that?

The following are corresponding MANIFEST.MF's:

Require-Bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: wsdl.classloading.test; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: wsdl.classloading.test.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.wst.wsdl;bundle-version="1.1.202",
 javax.wsdl;bundle-version="1.4.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Import-Package:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: wsdl.classloading.test; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: wsdl.classloading.test.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.wst.wsdl;bundle-version="1.1.202"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Import-Package: javax.wsdl,
 javax.wsdl.factory,
 javax.wsdl.xml
```

Comment: Are you using Require-Bundle for your dependencies, or Import-Package? Hint: you should be using Import-Package! Please don't "simplify for readability"... we need to see the exact dependency declarations from the relevant MANIFEST.MFs.

Comment: Thanks Neil. In fact I tried both Require-Bundle and Import-Package and got different results in dev and release environment.  Require-Bundle doesn't work for either one.  Import-Package works in the dev environment but not in the release environment.

I think it comes down to the question of the real meaning of Import-Package.  Does it NOT load highest version of the plug-in?

Comment: I will update my question to include MANIFEST.MF. Thanks for the hint, Neil!

Comment: But... your "Import-Package" bundle is still using Require-Bundle! I think the problem is likely as follows: org.eclipse.wst.wsdl is importing javax.wsdl and "re-exporting" it. Because you are using Require-Bundle for org.eclipse.wst.wsdl, you are getting its version in addition to the one you have imported. Basically Require-Bundle is evil, this kind of problem should never happen with pure Import-Package (unless other stuff is going on like bootdelegation=*, etc).

Comment: Thanks Neil.  In fact if org.eclipse.wst.wsdl "re-exports" javax.wsdl, all problems would go away.  My plugin can just put org.eclipse.wst.wsdl in Require-Bundle, and does not need to specify dependencies on javax.wsdl at all.  This way no matter what versions of javax.wsdl are available, my plugins would pick up the correct classes via org.eclipse.wst.wsdl.